# Spawn workers to use up nearly all available CPU

Tags: process, cpu-usage, supervisord

Say I have a CLI app that I want to do some work (e.g. process some media files). When I run one instance of the app it takes say 20% CPU. The rest 80% is idle.

I want some sort of process manager that will run as many app instances as it takes to use nearly all the CPU up. The app knows what to do and how not to interfere with its siblings, but it can't spawn/manage itself.

Is there any manager like that? I've been using supervisor to run fixed sets of different apps one instance each, but I don't know if it can be used to run variable amount of instances of the same app depending on CPU availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maximum overkill there is software such as `HTCondor` though such
frameworks typically have a high setup cost and longer learning curve
than your case may need.

A simpler but less flexible solution would be to write a small script
that checks the current CPU load and from that decides whether to `wait`
for a process to exit or to spawn one or more jobs (and then to `wait`
for a process to exit). This sort of script is probably where things
like `HTCondor` evolved from.

Even simpler might be to have a `Makefile` and then use `make -j 4 ...`
where one knows that each "job" takes up 20% - 25% of the CPU. This
assumes you know how much CPU the jobs take up, and that you know the jobs and can list them all in a `Makefile`. So not very flexible, unless you maybe generate the `Makefile` from a jobs list.

Comment: Huh, quite suprised there isn't anything simple and handy for this in 2022! It's hard to predict how much CPU each job will take (depends on the material it works with), so, perhaps, I'll have to write something from scratch to manage them.

Comment: There are likely job scheduling scripts or modules for various programming languages that allow batch job handling, though I'd probably write something tailored to the specific need... if your needs are more complicated then it likely makes sense to investiage and learn a scheduler with features. (Besides CPU there might be memory usage, disk I/O concerns, is someone at the keyboard...)